# How to blend two divs with blur without glitching it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to blur everything around the center of the camera, I've got close to it by putting 4 divs around the center and applying backdrop-filter:blur(5px) to them. But I got this weird blur glitch when containers are together, have tried putting them over with transform: scale but got the same issue. Anyone has any idea?

[image]

Comment: Please share the minimal code to reproduce the error you are experiencing

Comment: More details is needed maybe a chunk of code, but a believe this can be helpful https://codepen.io/qertis/pen/RNPXee

Comment: could you use clip-mask inner?